# sorting files and read according to basename in R

Tags: r, list, file

This question may have asked before, but I could not get how to do it. I have some files stored in different folders, say folder1, folder2, folder3. I want to sort these files according to their basename and create a list of dataframe. This is what I have done.

```
files1<-list.files("a/b/c/folder1/",pattern=".csv",full.names=T)
files2<-list.files("a/b/c/folder2/",pattern=".csv",full.names=T)
files3<-list.files("a/b/c/folder3/",pattern=".csv",full.names=T)

# Create a list to sort the files
files<-c(files1,files2,files3)
newlist<-sort(basename(files))
```

This will give the sorted list of files according to their basename, a01.csv, b02.csv..etc.

I try to read the sorted list of files but now I don't have the pathname so I am not able to read them.

```
readfiles<-lapply(newlist,function(x){read.csv(x,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)})
```

Is there any way to read this sorted list of files?

Comment: What error are you getting? Looks everything good to me

Comment: I am getting this error:  Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection. It is because now the files have only basename, not the full path so I am not able to read them

Comment: `files[order(basename(files))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `order` to get an ordered vector of indices to rearrange the original vector of files:

```
files <- c("path/b01.csv","path/a01.csv", "path/a02.csv")
files[order(basename(files))]

[1] "path/a01.csv" "path/a02.csv" "path/b01.csv"
```